# Notification on current user refresh?

Tags: parse-platform

I need to fetch some extra information after current user have been logged in.
I'm a bit lost in the "automatic" login flow, once user have already been logged in and app restart, loading user session from disk and refreshing.
I would like to get notified (one way or another) when it happen.

Any idea? track?

Comment: I've added a issue to discuss about this on the Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX github: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/620

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the main problems I encountered when using automatic user log in, and I have not figured out a solution yet. [I asked about it here on the parse gh repo](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/463). I could not use the `init` method of the subclass, because I had to modify the object on automatic user creation (which the library asserts on), but in your case, you could use this technique to be notified of the user creation. (create user subclass, register it, and override init method)

Comment: thx! how can i differentiate the current user from any other init? I really wish there was just a simple notification post on automatic login..

Comment: I'm not totally sure about that... We might have to wait for the official integration...